# React: Tailwind CSS can't seem to mimic bootstraps col-md-6?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to put my box / form inside box in the very center of my screen (which I've done), but its very narrow? I've tried adding `w-full` to various elements but just can't get it to mimic half of the screen width or full for that matter, nothing I do will allow me to change the width?

I am using react, here is my component: import React from 'react';

```
    import { LockClosedIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
    
    function App() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="flex h-screen">
                    <div className="m-auto">
                        <div className="shadow font-medium bg-white rounded-md flex p-10 pt-4 items-center justify-center w-max">
                            <form className="space-y-6" action="#" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="remember" defaultValue="true" />
                                <div className="rounded-md shadow-sm -space-y-px">
                                    <div>
                                        <label htmlFor="email-address" className="sr-only">
                                            Email address
                                        </label>
                                        <input
                                            id="email-address"
                                            name="email"
                                            type="email"
                                            autoComplete="email"
                                            required
                                            className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                                            placeholder="Email address"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label htmlFor="password" className="sr-only">
                                            Password
                                        </label>
                                        <input
                                            id="password"
                                            name="password"
                                            type="password"
                                            autoComplete="current-password"
                                            required
                                            className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                                            placeholder="Password"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                                    <div className="flex items-center">
                                        <input
                                            id="remember-me"
                                            name="remember-me"
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            className="h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500 border-gray-300 rounded"
                                        />
                                    </div>
    
                                    <div className="text-sm">
                                        <a href="#" className="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
                                            Forgot your password?
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                                <div>
                                    <button
                                        type="submit"
                                        className="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                                    >
                  <span className="absolute left-0 inset-y-0 flex items-center pl-3">
                    <LockClosedIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-indigo-500 group-hover:text-indigo-400" aria-hidden="true" />
                  </span>
                                        Sign in
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Near the top of your JSX, I think there are two changes you want to make:

- Set the width of the 3rd `div` to your desired width. `md:w-1/2` is like `col-md-6` in Bootstrap, I believe.
- Remove `w-max` from the 4th `div` as that limits the width of that element to the content within. `w-full` might have been what you wanted, but even that doesn't seem necessary once you set the with of it's parent element.

Here's the outer JSX elements with those changes:

```js
<div>
    <div className="flex h-screen">
        <div className="m-auto md:w-1/2">
            <div className="shadow font-medium bg-white rounded-md flex p-10 pt-4 items-center justify-center">
                {/* ... */}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```